# Как правильно перевести размер картинки в Мб?

Tags: java, android

Получаю размер картинки вот так:

```
image.getByteCount()
```

эту цифру делю на 1024, чтобы получить Мб, но получается неправильно.

Например: image.getByteCount() выдает 3048192 в байтах / 1024 = 2976,75 
а реальный размер 430.7 кб.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я подозреваю что, вы получаете не байты, а биты) 1 байт = 8 бит
Тогда:

```
3048192 / 1024 / 8 = 372 кб ( +58.6 кб системной информации зависит от формата файла и системы )
```

http://informatika.edusite.ru/lezione10_10i.htm

P.S.

Либо если это *.JPEG(жипег), то вы шакалов видели?)) В этом формате присутствует сжатие, причём очень высокое, так-что лучше измеряйте готовый файл того формата в котором будете хранить ваши изображения

Comment: "Я подозреваю что, вы получаете не байты, а биты" - Почему?

Comment: название метода `getByteCount` как бы намекает, что всё же это байты

Comment: Я не утверждаю, я предположил, на моей практике был случай работы с функцией у которой была неточность в терминологии, если это не так просто поправьте и скажите, что это гарантированно не так -- я исправлю, я просто увидел совпадение

Comment: Меня тоже смутило название функции, но я поверил, что это байты, а зря. Это действительно оказались биты, но я не догадался это проверить, тупанул.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, если "цифру делить на 1024", получатся килобайты.

Во-вторых, подозреваю, что речь идет о размере файла. В файл картинки сохраняются десятками способов в зависимости от формата и сжатия.